# Move square using canvas and p5.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, p5.js

I am trying to get a square to move using p5.js and HTML5's canvas element.

I have tried re-arranging the code in multiple ways, sometimes when code is in certain places the canvas doesn't create in the first place. No matter how many times I tried, I can't seem to get it to work.

The reason it is using the variable "direction" is because I plan on making it move based on the arrow key being pressed.

My code looks like this:

```js
var snakeX = 0;
var snakeY = 0;
var snakeX2 = 20;
var snakeY2 = 20;
var direction = "right";
var alive = true;
var length = 2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  frameRate(10);
}

function draw() {

  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(255);
  rect(snakeX, snakeY, snakeX2, snakeY2);
}

if (direction == "up") {
  snakeY = snakeY + 10
  snakeY2 = snakeY - length
}

function move() {
  if (direction == "down") {

    snakeY = snakeY - 10
    snakeY2 = snakeY + length
  }
  
  if (direction == "right") {
    snakeX = snakeX + 10
    snakeX2 = snakeX - length
  }

  if (direction == "left") {

    snakeX = snakeX - 10
    snakeX2 = snakeX + length
  }
  
  loop()
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
</body>
```

I expected the square to start moving to the right automatically when I open the page, however it remaining stationary. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the issues with animation can be resolved by doing the following:

- Add the call to `move()` in your `draw()` function
- Optionally add the `if(direction == 'up') { .. }` block into `move()`

Here's your snippet updated, to show this in action:

```js
var snakeX = 0;
var snakeY = 0;
var snakeX2 = 20;
var snakeY2 = 20;
var direction = "right";
var alive = true;
var length = 2

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  frameRate(10);
}

function draw() {

  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(255);
  rect(snakeX, snakeY, snakeX2, snakeY2);
  
  /* Ensure move() is called for each draw() */
  move()
}


function move() {

  /* Move this inside the brackets of move() */
  if (direction == "up") {
    snakeY = snakeY + 10
    snakeY2 = snakeY - length
  }
  
  if (direction == "down") {

    snakeY = snakeY - 10
    snakeY2 = snakeY + length
  }
  
  if (direction == "right") {
    snakeX = snakeX + 10
    snakeX2 = snakeX - length
  }

  if (direction == "left") {

    snakeX = snakeX - 10
    snakeX2 = snakeX + length
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: now the square moves but it doesnt remain a square... oh what is wrong with me XD

Comment: That's because you're incrementing `snakeX2` at a faster rate to `snakeX`, which is causing the different (or distance) between the two to increase over time. Let me know if you want something else and I can advise :-)

Comment: okay, so i got that fixed  ( i didnt realise that the third and fourth values and a rect() were width and height)  but i added another function and it made the canvas not show up...

Comment: @soconfoosion great to hear it's fixed - would you like to upload your updated code to github, jsFiddle or codepen and we can pick this up there?

Comment: yeah sure! actually its already uploaded to github, i use github to test my pages and actually to host them anyways! i was just doing a little bit of testing so let me revert it back to where it was(by testing i mean screwing it up more...)

Comment: @soconfoosion thanks, I just forked, fixed, and created a PR to master. You should see that on github. Have a look at the changes I made to see what was needed for the fix. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: ... so im confused, why when i add too many functions does the canvas not load at all? or when i call them in the draw function? sorry im a newbie here...

Comment: Nah, you can add as many functions as you like. The problem you had was basically a few syntax errors ie misplaced brackets etc